# authentication against ADFS, authorization against sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, authorization, adfs

after several days of searching, reading and trial and error i definitely need some help.

**The Situation**:
I need to create a Web-Application using MVC where users are authenticated against an AD using ADFS. But they do not want to store the Roles and further Informations into the AD. So i need to read and store those informations somewhere else. My first thougt was to use the same infrastructure which VS sets up when i created a new Web-Application and choose "Individual User Accounts".

**What i've done so far**:

- I created a new Projekt in VS and implemented the authentication against the AD using the ADFS (using this really helpful link(http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/02/12/use-the-on-premises-organizational-authentication-option-adfs-with-asp-net-in-visual-studio-2013/). Works fantastic.
- Start eating my Keyboard because i can't get the next step done.

**My Question/s**:
Is this possible to authenticate users using the ADFS and retrieve further informations (like Roles, other properties (e.g. Department)) about the logged in user by using / extending the ASP.NET Identity Framework? Does someone have a nice link?

I'd be glad for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is that you have to map the AD claims to the ASP.NET Identity via some kind of primary key.

Good link here : [Code! MVC 5 App with Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn and Google OAuth2 Sign-on (C#)](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on).

(With ADFS 4.0 (Server 2016) you will be able to use a SQL DB for authentication and authorization).

Answer (score 2):

No need to do the work in your web app...

You can simply have ADFS source the claim info from a SQL database.

Do *Add Attribute Store..*
Set *Attribute store type* to *SQL*
Enter a *Display name* and your *Connection string*

Then when adding the claim to the relying party choose a *Claim type*
of "... Custom Rule" and have the query you enter fetch the attributes from your DB.

There's a pretty good walkthru with more details in [TechNet](http://blogs.technet.com/b/vinitt/archive/2013/04/15/how-to-use-to-custom-sql-attribute-store-to-generate-claims-and-authorize-user.aspx)